# polars PyCharm warning when using the separator keyword argument

Tags: pycharm, python-polars

MRE:

`Python 3.11.1`

`PyCharm 2023.3.4 (Professional Edition)`

`pip install polars`

```py
import polars as pl

df: pl.DataFrame = pl.read_csv(
    "my_csv.csv",
    separator=";",
)
```

hovering on the method does indicate that the keyword argument separator can be used, as expected:
[image]

However, the static type checker indicates "unexpected argument":
[image]

How can I fix this? I am not allowed to use another IDE than PyCharm nor am I allowed to disable certain warnings with no quality assessments tags.

Comment: Do other functions work as expected? Does it work with `from polars import read_csv` instead of `pl.read_csv`? Do you have language server settings that are different from type checker settings?

Comment: What are language server settings?

Comment: Maybe it's called something different in pycharm. That's a thing in VSC but it should exist in some form in pycharm.